# Dashify in lingproc

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using lingproc.bst (http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~pgc/archive/1998/lingproc.bst) and lingproc.sty (http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~pgc/archive/temp/latex/sty/lingproc.sty). At the bottom of the latter, it says you can turn off the dashify and ampersand instead of 'and' functions by turning the comments on. I can only get the latter to work, however, and really want to turn off the dashify feature. When I try, it just completely removes the first instance of a dashified bibliography entry and then continues to dashify the second. Any ideas?

Here's a link to my files (including a `.zip` of all of them): https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3Si8J4jDIwaVEF0NFNnRnVnekE&usp=sharing

Here's the skeleton of my file (I've taken out the body).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lingproc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{language_policy_in_belarus.bib}    
@misc{beldig11a,
   author = {{Belarus Digest}},
   title = {Are the {B}elarusian and {R}ussian languages very similar?},
   volume = {2013},
   number = {25 December 2013},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Web Page},
   note = {Available at: http://belarusdigest.com/myth/are-belarusian-and-russian-languages-very-similar-371 [Accessed 25 December 2013]}
}

@misc{beldig11b,
   author = {{Belarus Digest}},
   title = {Is the language issue important in {B}elarus?},
   volume = {2013},
   number = {25 December 2013},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Web Page},
   note = {Available at: http://belarusdigest.com/myth/language-issue-important-belarus-2092 [Accessed 25 December 2013]}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{lingproc}
\bibliography{language_policy_in_belarus}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar No I didn't comment it out like that, but that didn't work either. I presume an MWE is an edit to the original post.

Comment: I don't know what mwe or MWE is, but I've but the main elements of the code in the document in my original post. I can send the whole thing, but I'd rather not post the entire body text on a public page.

Comment: I have modified your code so that it can be called a MWE. Please  replace `<put one or two bib enteries here from your language_policy_in_belarus.bib file>` in the code above with what that line says.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks - still not sure what an MWE is! I've added a couple of the entries from the `.bib` file.

Comment: Now the above is called MWE :) for details: http://goo.gl/dtPzv

Comment: @HarishKumar Done!

Comment: @HarishKumar That's the first instance of a duplicate author - there's one more later on, but the accompanying authors change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Amend the following two four-line blocks in the `.bst` from...

```
%       { "\lsadashifynew{" t * "}" *}
%       { "\lsadashify{" t * "}" *}
            { "\lsadashifynew{}"}
            { "\lsadashify{}"}
```

... and...

```
%            { "\lsadashifynew{" t * "}." * 't :=}
%            { "\lsadashify{" t * "}." * 't :=}
                 { "\lsadashifynew{}" 't :=}
                 { "\lsadashify{}" 't :=}
```

... to:

```
        { "\lsadashifynew{" t * "}" *}
        { "\lsadashify{" t * "}" *}
%           { "\lsadashifynew{}"}
%           { "\lsadashify{}"}
```

... and...

```
             { "\lsadashifynew{" t * "}." * 't :=}
             { "\lsadashify{" t * "}." * 't :=}
%                { "\lsadashifynew{}" 't :=}
%                { "\lsadashify{}" 't :=}
```

This effectively reverts this function back to what it was on the parent `.bst` file 'lsalike'.

Then amend the end of the `.sty` from...

```
\def\lsadashify#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}

\def\lsadashifynew#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
%\def\lsadashifynew#1{#1}

\def\lsaand{\& }
%\def\lsaand{and }
```

... to:

```
%\def\lsadashify#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
\def\lsadashify#1{#1}

%\def\lsadashifynew#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
\def\lsadashifynew#1{#1}

\def\lsaand{\& }
%\def\lsaand{and }
```

Also, if you would prefer 'and' instead of '&' in citations and the bibliography, swap the comments on the last pair of lines.

Thanks to Harish for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

First in `lingproc.sty` do this:

```
%\def\lsadashify#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
%%
%\def\lsadashifynew#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
\def\lsadashifynew#1{#1}


%\def\lsaand{\& }
\def\lsaand{and }
```

Save it (preferably with a different name (`mylingproc.sty`) in the same folder as your main tex document).

Then your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mylingproc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{language_policy_in_belarus.bib}
@article{bekus13,
   author = {Bekus, Nelly and Me},
   title = {Ethnic identity in post-{S}oviet {B}elarus: ethnolinguistic survival as an argument in the political struggle},
   journal = {Journal of Multilingual and Multicultural Development},
   pages = {1--16},
   year = {2013},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@misc{beldig11a,
   author = {{Bekus, Nelly and Me}},
   title = {Are the {B}elarusian and {R}ussian languages very similar?},
   volume = {2013},
   number = {25 December 2013},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Web Page},
   note = {Available at: http://belarusdigest.com/myth/are-belarusian-and-russian-languages-very-similar-371 [Accessed 25 December 2013]}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{lingproc}
\bibliography{language_policy_in_belarus}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fingers crossed. Hope it will work in your real file :)

**Notes**

If you change the name of `lingproc.sty` to `mylingproc.sty` (say), you have to put it in the same folder as your main tex file. On the other hand, you can put it in your localtexmf folder also. You have to change `\usepackage{lingproc}` to `\usepackage{mylingproc}` in your tex file.

The `filecontents` package and the `filecontents*` environment are meant to be used only in this MWE, not in your tex file. The same is true for `\nocite{*}` Don't use them in your tex file since you have cited all the references already.

*8Last edit**

Your files work fine for me. Only error was the use of `\usepackage{lingproc}`. Use `\usepackage{mylingproc}` instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I modify the `.sty` file, change its name and put it in the same folder as my `.tex` file? Do I need to change the code so that it can find it?

Do I need to do that `\usepackage{filecontents}` code and then include the bibliography items for the duplicates? Do I have to do `\nocite` if I've cited all the bibliography items in the body?

Comment: Hmm, I made those edits to the `lingproc.sty` file and just saved it where it was before, and that didn't fix it. Would it make a difference if it were a different `.sty` file?

Comment: The error persists even if I modify the `.sty` and put it in the same folder as the `.tex` file. It was in the 'texmf' directory. I don't know what running texhash means.

Comment: It does. I'm using TeXShop on OS X (a MacBook).

Comment: Should I send you my files?

Comment: I've added that to the question. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @andylaw31 Your files work fine too for me. You have to use `\usepackage{mylingproc}` instead of `\usepackage{lingproc}`. Also delete all `.aux` .synctex` etc files. I am adding a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks Harish - I will try this when I get home. What are the font encoding issues?

Comment: I get various warnings, but mostly about citations. Everything seems fine apart from the dashes though. I see that the Harbacki entry has come out wrong on your screenshot but it works on mine. Just to clarify, I don't need to put the `.bst` file in the same folder, just the `.sty`, and then rename the `.sty` and update the `\usepackage` and `\bibliographystyle` bits.

Comment: Should the `.bst` be renamed 'mylingproc' too?

Comment: Okay I've changed both the `\usepackage` and the `\bibliographystyle` to 'mylingproc' and put both the `.bst` and `.sty` (both named 'mylingproc') into the same folder. It didn't work so I tried editing the `.sty` to `%\def\lsadashify#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
\def\lsadashify#1{#1}

%\def\lsadashifynew#1{---\hspace*{-2pt}---}
\def\lsadashifynew#1{#1}


%\def\lsaand{\& }
\def\lsaand{and }` - I've added an alternative for the 'lsadashify' command. This now produces empty space in place of both duplicate names. So the command/`{#1}` is replacing the author with nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it by switching the comments in the `.bst` file so that the functions returned to how they were in the 'lsalike' files that these were based on. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @andylaw31 Glad it worked. Thanks are better conveyed by up voting and accepting the answers. For details refer to [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)